# Testing if a user input is a variable name and then evaluating it Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, variables, input, python-3.6

I have two files, `resourceIDS` and `start.py` I want the user to input a string like "Regolith" in the `start.py` file and then grab the variable `resourceIDS.ResourceIDS.RID_Regolith` I have tried using exec() and eval()
but to no avail most probably because I am using it wrong.

Example:

#### `resourceIDS.py`

```
class ResourceIDS:
    RID_Regolith = 10
```

#### `start.py`

```
import resourceIDS
user_input = input("RID:" )
--pseudo code--
if (resourceIDS.ResourceIDS.RID_ + user_input) is a variable in resourceIDS:
    give me the value (like 10 for the example)
    variable = the value
```

How can I achieve this in any way?

I tried this, I am very new to exec() and eval() so I'm not even sure if I should've used exec() this way

```
print("Adding a resource!")
rid = input("Resource Name: ")
rid = "ResourceIDS.RID_" + rid

if rid.isidentifier():
    x = rid
    exec("%s = %s" % ("a", x))
```

Comment: Post what you've tried, you might be using eval() wrong

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote

Comment: Writing up answer, bare with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**resourceIDS.py**

```
class resourceIDS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.RID_Regolith = 10
```

**start.py**

```
import resourceIDS
user_input = input("RID: ")
value = eval('resourceIDS.resourceIDS().RID_' + user_input)
```

You needed to initiate the class first; before your resourceIDS.py wasnt doing anything. I imported it as resourceIDS so to access the class within the file, I do resourceIDS.resourceIDS(), if change `import resourceIDS` to `from resourceIDS import *`, you can instead type resourceIDS()

Comment: Does the `self.RID_Regolith` have to be in a `__init___` or can it be used like I showed in the example above?

Comment: You cannot use it like in your example, sorry.

Comment: It has to be in the `__init__` as that is what initiates the class variables directly related to the class. If you are unsure of what I mean, play around a bit more with classes - @MaxBethke

Comment: I forgot to put in my question but the Resource IDS has a Enum passed into it from `from enum import Enum` and so an init doesn't seem to work